Convex lower-approximation of a non-convex function
Assume I have a function $f(x)$ which is discontinuous and non-convex in $x$, possibly not known explicitly. Assume I know lower bounds at a number of points, say $(x_1,LB_1), (x_2,LB_2), \ldots,(x_N,LB_n)$.
Question: What are techniques I could use to obtain a function $g(x)$, possibly linear, such that $f(x)\geq g(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain?

Random noise seeded by x is a discontinuous and non-convex function falling into the category you wish to bound. Thinking about how your function differs from completely unpredictable noise may reveal properties that could be useful. And if your function is noise, maybe you are looking for statistical bounds satisfied at certain probability?

When the function is known, to compute a convex lower approximation of a non-convex function, we use the Legendre–Fenchel transform twice. The Legendre–Fenchel transform of a function $h: X \mapsto R$ is given by $h^*(x^*) = \sup_{x \in X} (x^* \cdot x - h(x))$ from the dual space of $X$, denoted $X^*$, into $R$. $f^{**}=(f^*)^*$ is the lower semicontinuous convex envelope of $f$. Note that $f$ shouldn't take the value $-\infty$ anywhere, and there should be at least one element $x$ such that $f(x) < \infty$, which is the case here.
Otherwise, I don't see how we can find a lower bound from a finite number of samples; we can't even find its minimum. You can always construct a counterexample: define a function that respects the provided bounds but behaves erratically elsewhere, and the bound will be violated.

Thanks @Abdellah . Would it help to know that one of the lower bouds is smaller than $\min_xf(x)$?

A simplistic answer would be to consider $g$ as a constant equal to $\min_{1 \leq k \leq n} LB_k$.

$g = \min_{1 \leq k \leq n} LB_k$ is the best we can do in this case, this bound is tight when $f$ is constant.
